# StatusBar App - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, statusbar

I saw this guide: http://vimeo.com/17110202
And now I want to upgrade this app and to use more options besides Menu.

I thought to myself that I want to build somthing like Spotlite ( same design )
But I dont know how to use more options except Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Apple published a [sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MenuItemView/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows how to embed `NSViews` inside `NSMenuItems`. The basic idea is to send `-[NSMenuItem setView:]` in order to change the visual representation of a menu item.

Comment: It not what I'm looking for. I was download the project but it isn't on the **StatusBar** on the ride where the spotlight, so how can i put it on the right statusbars?

Comment: @Daniel A status bar item has a menu associated to it. Apple’s sample project shows how to change a menu so as to use views different from what `NSMenu`/`NSMenuItem` provide. Isn’t that what you’re looking for? If not, what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

As i read, it is not possible to change the view of a NSMenuItem in a StatusBar app